# How can I fix this Excel formula in ordert to exlude rows from calculation when two different columns has a specific value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not so into Excel and I am finding the following difficulty trying to adapt a pre-existing formula to a new requirement.

Basically I have this original formula (workiong fine):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D7)*(B2:B7="BUY"))/SUMPRODUCT((G2:G7)*(B2:B7="BUY"))
```

This basically calculate an avarange price checking that the value of the B column is "BUY" (basically to exclude when the row is a SELL row). It works fine.

Now I have to change the previous formula excluding also all the row having the H column having value different from "CC". I have try in this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D7)*(B2:B7="BUY" AND H2:H7="CC"))/SUMPRODUCT((G2:G7)*(B2:B7="BUY" AND H2:H7="CC"))
```

Basically I tried to add an **AND** condition checking if the **H** column value is **CC**. But it is not working. It give me a syntax error when I try to insert this second version of my forumula.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix my formula?

Answer (score 1):

1. `AND` is used `AND(crit1,crit2)` not `crit1 AND crit2`.
2. `AND` will not work in this case.

Use `*` instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D7)*(B2:B7="BUY")*(H2:H7="CC"))/SUMPRODUCT((G2:G7)*(B2:B7="BUY")*(H2:H7="CC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For `AND` either use this logic: `AND(B2:B7="BUY",H2:H7="CC")` or `(B2:B7="BUY")*(H2:H7="CC")` in the second one `*` stands for `AND`, but as pointed out by Scott Craner in array formulas (such as SUMPRODUCT) you have to use `*`.

Comment: `AND()` will not work even if corrected to the proper format.

Comment: Ok learned something new. Is it because it can't be used in arrays?

Comment: That is correct.  AND will fully resolve before passing a single result out.  It will not return an array.